# VS Code: Removing the activitybar

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to hide the activitybar on the left side.

[image: Activitybar image]

I call it the activitybar because when I look in developer tools it's called activitybar.

[image: Developer tools in VS Code]

When I search for activitybar in the "User Settings" file I cannot find anything called activitybar or activity for that matter.

Is it possible to hide this element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature right now in settings, you can make your own build of VSCode and try to implement such toggler functionality, it is possible because it's open-source.

Comment: It is now possible to hide the activity bar https://code.visualstudio.com/raw/images/1_8/hide-activitybar.gif

Comment: You can right click on it now too and click 'Hide Activity Bar' although I don't see how to get it to appear again without going through the command palatte.